# Unable to get Meteor-Pagination to work

Tags: pagination, meteor

I am trying to add pagination support to my meteor app but my template shows a blank page as soon as I add the {{{pagination}}} tag in my template.  There are no errors in the log.

My client js (routing info) looks like this

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/': function () {
  var user;

  if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
   console.log('home: loading');
   return 'loading';
  }

 user = Meteor.user();
 if (!user) {
  console.log('homer: signin');
  return 'user_signin';
 }

  // start on 'start' page
  console.log('home: start');
  return 'page';
  },

  '/landing':       'landing',
  '*':              'not_found',

  '/landing/:page': function (page) {
   Session.set('page', page) ;
   return 'landing' ;
  }
  });
```

My Landing.js looks like this

```
  Template.userList.pagination = function () {
  return Pagination.links('/landing', Meteor.users.find({}).count(), {currentPage: Session.get('page'), perPage: 8}) ;
 }
```

My landing template is as follows:

```
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {{#each users}}
                          {{> user}}
                        {{/each}}
                        {{{pagination}}}
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with the pagination package not rendering the results but showing the correct 'next' and 'prev' links. Are you're results being rendered with Pagination.Collection

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things with the code posted.

1. I don't know much about the Pagination addin but it looks like you have it inside the table tag and according to this (https://github.com/egtann/meteor-pagination) it renders a div. I believe that would be invalid.
2. In your routes you have the wildcard `'*'` before the `'landing/:page'`. I believe it would match that one first. Should have the `'*'` be the last route you add.